# SDWebImage is not working in iOS 4.3 how to solve it

Tags: ios4

I am using SDWebImage framework 3.0 but its is not working in iOS 4.3

How to use SDWebimage in ios4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage framework 2.0 instead, it works well with iOS 4.3